# how does javascript's closure work if we want to preserve a value in currying

Tags: javascript, closures

I have written the code

```
// Handlers
function successHandlerFactory (savedFlag) {

  return function (res, savedFlag){
    if (res.data && res.status == 200) {
      ngcoupon_offerManager.addOffers(res.data.offers, -1, savedFlag);
      console.log('offers response', res, 'savedFlag', savedFlag);
    } else {
      console.error('something is wrong to get offers', res);
    }
  }
};

var offerSuccessHandler = function() {
    return successHandlerFactory();
}();
var savedofferSuccessHandler = function () {
  return successHandlerFactory(true);
}();
```

but apparently its giving out `savedFlag undefined` every executinon I make.

How come this does not work

Comment: What does code have to do with closures? Please explain,

Comment: Have you already looked at [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)?

Comment: Change `return function (res, savedFlag){` to `return function (res){`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Already fixed.

Comment: Why not `var offerSuccessHandler = successHandlerFactory()` instead of the IIFE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in this part of the code:

```
function successHandlerFactory (savedFlag) {
  return function (res, savedFlag){
    ...
```

You're re-declaring `savedFlag` in the inner function, which ends up being the variable that is captured in the success handler. Try simply removing the second parameter of the returned function.